# How To Apply Full Camera Functions Using SurfaceView Android

Tags: android, xml, camera, surfaceview

I am working on a project in Android using Surface View Camera. I want to show some buttons along with a frame on the Surface View of camera and make it the camera capturing functionality.

Now I am done up to SurfaceView to view frame image above the camera but when I add buttons it shows outside the surface view. Below is my main code:

//This is my **PreviewDemo.java**

```
    package com.commonsware.android.camera;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
     import android.hardware.Camera;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
     import android.view.SurfaceView;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     public class PreviewDemo extends Activity {
     private SurfaceView preview=null;
     private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
     private Camera camera=null;
     private boolean inPreview=false;
     private boolean cameraConfigured=false;
     LayoutInflater inflater = null;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(view, layoutParamsControl);
     }

     @Override
    public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

    camera=Camera.open();
    startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    if (inPreview) {
      camera.stopPreview();
    }

    camera.release();
    camera=null;
    inPreview=false;

    super.onPause();
    }

    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                         Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
      if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
        if (result==null) {
          result=size;
        }
        else {
          int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
          int newArea=size.width*size.height;

          if (newArea>resultArea) {
            result=size;
          }
        }
       }
     }

    return(result);
     }

    private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
    if (camera!=null && previewHolder.getSurface()!=null) {
      try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
              "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
        Toast
          .makeText(PreviewDemo.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
      }

      if (!cameraConfigured) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                                            parameters);

        if (size!=null) {
          parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
          camera.setParameters(parameters);
          cameraConfigured=true;
        }
      }
      }
      }

      private void startPreview() {
      if (cameraConfigured && camera!=null) {
      camera.startPreview();
      inPreview=true;
      }
     }

     SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
     }

     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
      initPreview(width, height);
       startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      // no-op
     }
    };
  }
```

//This is my **Overlay.Xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:padding="@android:dimen/thumbnail_height" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question. But, if you wish to show a 'Capture' button above a surface view on a frame try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/frame"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Capture" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:longClickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the button be placed after the SurfaceView?

Comment: Thanks,One more Dobut Can I add This Button With I The SurFace View

Comment: Sure it is. Just remove the android:layout_below="@id/button1" tag in the relative layout

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly.
You're trying to add an overlay that will show buttons ontop of the video preview.
For that purpose you need to use relative layout which lays (by default) views ontop of each other.
After putting the SurfaceView you can put whatever view you like and use its attributes to align it on screen the way you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:padding="@android:dimen/thumbnail_height" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    // PUT YOUR BUTTONS HERE
</FrameLayout

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My mistake. Since we changed to RelativeLayout the height of the surface view should be "wrap_content" or "fill_parent". I've edited the answer.